# Querying a Contact entity based on AssignedToName

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am writing an API using the CRM SDK to get a contact based on an "assignedToName" which can be a systemuser name or a team name.
I am using QueryExpressions. Question is how to create the query expression and the LinkEntities for this? 
Currently the QueryExpression for Contact has 2 Link Entities using LeftOuter joins.
One from Contact to SystemUser on the AssignedToID = SystemUserID field
and another from Contact to Team on AssignedToID = TeamID field with a ConditionExpression for the "Name" field = "assignedToName"

The reason for having 2 link entities is because I do not know whether the "assignedToName" belongs to a Team or to a User.

The side effect of this is that now I have false positives in the results where in extra contact records are being included in the  result set due to the LeftOuter join. What is the correct way of writing the QueryExpression for this?

Sample Code:

```cs
 private IEnumerable<Entity> GetContactEntities(string assignedToName, IOrganizationService orgService)
    {
        QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression("contact");
        LinkEntity linkSystemUser = new LinkEntity("contact", "systemuser", "assignedtoid", "systemuserid", JoinOperator.LeftOuter);
        LinkEntity linkTeam = new LinkEntity("contact", "team", "assignedtoid", "teamid", JoinOperator.LeftOuter);
        linkSystemUser.LinkCriteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("name",ConditionOperator.Equal,assignedToName));
        linkSystemUser.EntityAlias = "linkSystemUser";
        linkTeam.LinkCriteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("name",ConditionOperator.Equal,assignedToName));
        linkTeam.EntityAlias = "linkTeam";
        qe.LinkEntities.Add(linkSystemUser);
        qe.LinkEntities.Add(linkTeam);
        return orgService.RetrieveMultiple(qe).Entities;
    }
```

Comment: You can create 2 queryexpression, the first linked with systemuser entity, if there are no results  execute the other one linked with team

Comment: @GuidoPreite: I was hoping not to round trip to CRM twice for this.